# updateViewConstraints gives "Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I have a View Controller that inits a child View Controller in ViewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    mapVC = [[CollectionMapViewController alloc] init];
}
```

It then adds this VC as a subview in an IBAction method:

```
- (IBAction)left_seg1:(id)sender {                
            [mapVC layoutMapView];
            [self.view addSubview:mapVC.view];
            NSLog(@"num 1");
            _tagTwo = 3;
            return;
}
```

I am trying to create constraints for the subview with respect to its parent view. In my attempt to do so, I have added updateViewConstraints to the parent class.

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints{
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    mapVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSLayoutConstraint* trailConstrain=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:mapVC.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:10];
    NSLayoutConstraint* leadingConstrain=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:mapVC.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:10];
    [self.view addConstraints:@[trailConstrain, leadingConstrain]];

}
```

However, this generates the following runtime exception:

```
Assertion failure in -[UIView _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:
roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.7.47/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:649
    **Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint**
```

I looked at other threads and the problem was that they had set up constraints in `viewDidLoad`, but I haven't done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Never never never call `viewDidLoad`. It's not your method to call. Delete that line immediately.

(2) The problem with your code is that you have no idea when it will be called. Add a check to make sure `mapVC.view` is in your interface; if not, don't run that code.

(3). You cannot just take a view controller's view and plunk it into your interface. You have to act as a parent view controller. You're not doing that. That's illegal.

Comment: Is there a specific way to find if a view is in my interface? Or would I just rely on an instance variable, for ex, `if (_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)`...Also, is adding a subview illegal? In what ways am I not acting as a parent view controller?

Comment: The view is not in your interface if its `window` is `nil`. — I have explained the parent view controller "dance" here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers